# What is the basic term sheet of joining of software company?

Tags: contract-law, employment

I'm not a law student. I'm just software engineer who only knows how to code.

I'm pretty confused. My friends are starting a software company and they are not software engineers; they have BBA degrees. They asked me to join their company as a software developer. I've got good skills, they asked me to sign a term sheet that says:

> Job is for 1 year only.
>   I can't quit the job during this time period.
>   They can terminate me
>   I have to work 8 hours a day

I'm new to working for a software company, because, this is my first job. I need help. I want to be able to quit the job anytime I want, I would give them one months notice before I quit. What if there's is project of one year. And, I started project, but I want to quit the job in the middle of the project. What would I do?

I'm in my last year as a student.

Comment: This neeeds clarification. Apart from what country you are in, you need to say whether you are asking "what should I do to achieve this?" (which is off-topic and possibly illegal to answer), or "what would the legal consequences be if I did this?" as well as exactly what *this* is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory is that you and they would write up an agreement – a contract – that says what you must do, and what they must do. One of the terms in such a contract could be that they have to keep you on for 1 year, and you have to keep working for them for 1 year: and there is no provision for quitting or them firing you. Your version of this agreement seems to allow them to fire you but you can't quit.

If such a contract is valid (I will assume Pakistan, and I don't know whether such a clause would be valid under the law of Pakistan), then if you quit, they could sue you. It is highly unlikely that the courts would order specific performance (that is, force you to go back to work for them), but they might be able to get some money from you for whatever damage you caused them. Your departure might cause significant upset to their project, so I would not discount the possibility that they could get a substantial award from the court.

I assume that the text you provided is a paraphrase and that the actual contract is clearer, and specifies that you will be paid.

Answer (score 0):

This is an offer - you don't have to accept it, and you don't have to accept it as it is.

Terms where you can be terminated but have no right to terminate yourself are unacceptable. There is no reason why you would ever consider accepting this. There should be a notice period stated, giving both the employer and yourself the possibility to quit the contract given that amount of notice.

Missing from the offer and quite important are your salary, when your salary is paid, your paid holidays, and the number of weekly working days. (You don't want to work 8 hours a day from monday to sunday I suppose).

These things MUST be in any contract that you would consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

This is an employment contract and will be covered by employment law in whatever jurisdiction the job is domiciled.

I am not aware of any jurisdiction on earth where slavery is legal so the therm that prohibits your leaving would be void, either being directly superseded by employment law or as contrary to public interest.